# Нужна ли указанная запятая? (3)

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксический-разбор

> Проценты с депозита помогут мне в будущем. И тебе помогут, хотя бы
> немного(,) - это ответ на твой вопрос.

Здравствуйте. Нужна ли указанная запятая? Что вообще из себя представляет второе предложение, почему стоит первая запятая, ведь "хотя бы" в данном случае - это частица и не выделяется запятыми... Или я не права?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Проценты с депозита помогут мне в будущем. **И тебе помогут, хотя бы немного,  — это ответ на твой вопрос.***

1. **Это БСП,** вторая часть имеет **присоединительный** характер.

**Розенталь** § 45. Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

Пункт 9. Если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения представляет собой **присоединительное предложение**, перед ней ставится **тире** (возможно вставить слово ***это***, которое иногда имеется в самом предложении):

*На стене ни одного образа — дурной знак (Л.); Души у вас нет, у вас самолюбие вместо души — **вот что** я вам скажу (Аж.); Инга была возбуждена, Левшин наблюдал за ней слишком пристально — ***это*** бросалось Клебе в глаза (Фед.);*

2. Сочетание ***хотя бы немного*** обособлено с целью **выделения дополнительной информации.** Частица с уступительным значением "хотя бы" обособляется вместе с наречием.

**Розенталь** § 20. Обособленные обстоятельства. Обстоятельства, выраженные наречиями http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=115#pp115

Могут обособляться (выделяться запятыми) о**бстоятельства, выраженные наречиями** (одиночными или в сочетании с зависимыми словами), с целью **смыслового выделения** или пояснения: *Меня, **как бы нечаянно**, обливали водой (Ч.); Проходя Театральным переулком, я, **почти всегда**, видел у двери маленькой лавки человека (М. Г.);*

Из словаря: **ХОТЯ. II. частица.** (с частицей бы). Хоть бы. Спойте х. бы немножко. Съешьте х. бы кусочек.